# Dynamic {site_name} inside channel:entries tag with site="" parameter

Tags: multi-site-manager

Anyone know if it's possible to get back the name of the site an entry is from dynamically? Simple code example below:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" site="siteA|siteB"}
  <h2>{title}</h2>
  <p>Published: {entry_date format="%j %M %Y"} in {site_name}</p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Tried using {site_name} and {site_label} but they just show the current site. Be nice to be able to get the site name and short name out.

Cheers, Ant

Answer (score 1):

For the name you could try a conditional with [entry_site_id](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#entry-site-id).

```
<p>Published: {entry_date format="%j %M %Y"} in {if entry_site_id == 1}Site name 1{/if}{if entry_site_id == 2}Site name 2{/if}</p>
```